# Is attaching a scenekit node to an ARAnchor just setting the transform of the node to that of the anchor?

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I read that to make "virtual objects appear to stay in place relative to the real world" in an AR scene you should use ARAnchors.

- Can I attach a scenekit node to an anchor I created other than by just setting the transform of the node to the values of the transform of the anchor? To me that doesn't really look like attaching it to the anchor, rather just placing them at the same 3D position.
- This wouldn't tell ARKit to update the nodes transform when the transform of the anchor changes. Am I right? I don't really see the point of using an anchor in this case.

Answer (score -1):

ARKit manages positions of anchors, and by extension of nodes attached to them by whatever transform necessary. So basically relative position of attached node remains intact however position of the anchor may change. You can also set constraints so that rotation is always the same towards the camera or some other node.

So, question #1: it can be any transform relative to anchor transform.
And question #2: see the explanation above, relative transform of node to anchor remains intact however anchor position may change.

Example of adding a sphere at the anchor position and a text label above it that will always face the camera:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    guard let featureAnchor = anchor as? FeatureAnchor else {
        return nil
    }
    let feature = featureAnchor.feature

    let billboardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
    billboardConstraint.freeAxes = SCNBillboardAxis.Y

    let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: Global.dotRadius)
    sphere.firstMaterial?.transparency = Global.annotationTransparency
    sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
    sphere.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
    node.constraints = [billboardConstraint]

    let text = SCNText(string: feature.description, extrusionDepth: Global.textDepth)
    text.chamferRadius = Global.textDepth
    text.firstMaterial?.transparency = Global.annotationTransparency
    text.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
    text.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white
    text.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    text.font = Global.textFont
    text.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter

    let (min, max) = text.boundingBox
    let dx: Float = (max.x - min.x) / 2.0 // x = center
    let dy: Float = min.y // y = bottom
    let dz: Float = Float(Global.textDepth) / 2.0 // z = center

    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)
    textNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(dx, dy, dz)
    textNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(Global.textScale, Global.textScale, Global.textScale)

    node.addChildNode(textNode)

    return node
}
```

Comment: How can I set a node's position relative to the anchor position?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: I see you're creating a new node called node and attach another one called textNode. Then you return the node "node". However I can't see where exactly node ("node") is attached to the anchor ("featureAnchor"). You retrieve the anchor as a FeatureAnchor, but don't do anything with it afterwards. Am I missing something?

Comment: Typically, and in this case as well, the main node for the anchor has the same transform as the anchor itself, and its children have relative transforms - in this case, `textNode` is the only child. From the 
 method docs: "Note that ARKit controls the node's visibility and its transform property, so you may find it useful to add child nodes or adjust the node's pivot property to maintain any changes to position or orientation that you make."

Comment: @nmnd the node attached to the anchor is returned by this method. iOS calls this method with an anchor, and you have to return the node that should be attached to it.

Comment: `FeatureAnchor` is not defined here, so this code will not work, not a great starting point for anyone.